# How to get \hyperref[…]{custom expression} in small caps?

Tags: hyperref, koma-script, small-caps

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter

\newtheoremstyle{style3}{\topsep}{}{}{}{\scshape}{}{ }{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2} --- \thmnote{#3}.}
\theoremstyle{style3}

\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}[]

\makeatother

% REFERENCES SETTINGS

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=blue}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\namerefOld\nameref
  \renewcommand{\nameref}[1]{\textsc{\namerefOld{#1}}}
}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\crefOld\cref
  \renewcommand{\cref}[1]{\textsc{\crefOld{#1}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{axiom}[Optimality]\label{opt}
    Fancy definition.
\end{axiom}

I am currently writing that object y satisfies \nameref{opt}, but I would rather say that object y is \hyperref[opt]{optimal}. The problem is that the word \hyperref[opt]{optimal} should be in small caps but isn't.
    
\end{document}
```

As can be seen in the output below, the problem is that the command `\hyperref[opt]{optimal}` is not producing its output in small caps. I could perhaps force it such that all hyperlinks are in small caps, but I am also providing hyperlinks to articles’ webpages in the References section, and I do NOT want those to be in small caps.

[image: Output]

I could of course write `\textsc{\hyperref[opt]{optimal}}` every single time, but I’d rather have that automated, if possible.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Just define `\newcommand\hyperrefSC[2][]{\hyperref[#1]{\textsc{#2}}}` in your preamble and use `\hyperrefSC` where needed (instead of `\hyperref`)

Comment: Another solution (to use the original command redefined) is to add these two commands just before your `\begin{document}` [in the given order]: `\let\oldhyperref\hyperref`
`\renewcommand\hyperref[2][]{\oldhyperref[#1]{\textsc{#2}}}` (But I would not suggest that option)

Comment: Thank you for your comments —your first solution works just fine and I like it. Also, I know this is bad practice, but do you know *how to force the first letter of `\nameref{…}`’s output to be lower-case rather than capital in my MWE?*

Comment: `pdfmanagement-testphase` package can do the trick. See a similar example https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/195#issuecomment-875004675.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this options to see if it helps:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter

\newtheoremstyle{style3}{\topsep}{}{}{}{\scshape}{}{ }{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2} --- \thmnote{#3}.}
\theoremstyle{style3}

\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}[]

\makeatother

% REFERENCES SETTINGS

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=blue}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\namerefOld\nameref
  \renewcommand{\nameref}[1]{{\let\dlower\lowercase\textsc{\namerefOld{#1}}}}
}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\crefOld\cref
  \renewcommand{\cref}[1]{\textsc{\crefOld{#1}}}
}


\newcommand\hyperrefSC[2][]{\hyperref[#1]{\textsc{#2}}}
\def\dlower#1{#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{axiom}[\dlower{O}ptimality]\label{opt}
    Fancy definition.
\end{axiom}

I am currently writing that object y satisfies \nameref{opt}, but I would rather say that object y is \hyperrefSC[opt]{optimal}. The problem is that the word \hyperrefSC[opt]{optimal} should be in small caps but isn't.
    
\end{document}
```

For your last request about lowercase thew first letter I placed it in a dummy command that is changed into a not dummy (`\lowercase`) inside the definition of `\nameref`